# What are the differences between symbolic execution and SAT solvers?

Tags: satisfiability, sat-solvers, smt-solvers, symbolic-execution

My understanding is that symbolic execution only deals with specific paths and bad patterns, while SAT solvers, or satisfiability modulo theories in general, provide a much more robust analysis of the program.

Could someone validate the statement above and (briefly) explain the differences between these two formal verification methodologies?

Comment: What research have you done, and what resources have you read and what have you found so far?

Comment: I'm not an expert in this field. Researching formal verification would've taken me weeks before I could come up with a mental model explainable to a 5-year old.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR:** They differ in their basic input and output. SAT and SMT solvers don't know what programs are; they are tools that answer yes or no questions about mathematical formulas. Symbolic execution, on the other hand, is a method of analyzing programs. Symbolic execution usually relies on SAT and SMT solvers, but not the other way around.

---

**SAT and SMT solvers** don't directly have anything to do with programs. Instead, a SAT or SMT solver takes as input a mathematically described "formula", and answers, roughly, whether it is true or false. (Often a third option is allowed, *unknown*, for cases where the solver is unable to figure out an answer.)

For example, a possible input to a SAT solver is `(a and not b) or (not a and c)`. That is, it is a mathematical formula, where `a`, `b`, and `c` here are Boolean (0 or 1) constants. The SAT solver is supposed to decide if it is possible for the formula to be true, by choosing values of `a`, `b`, and `c`. SMT solvers are similar, but `a`, `b`, and `c` would be replaced by more complex formulas using integers, strings, functions, etc., for example `x + 3 = y^2`.

---

**Symbolic execution** is a fancy way of running a program, but not how the program was intended to be run. Instead, the program is run using so-called "symbolic" values, which are kind of like placeholders. For an example of what that means, suppose I have a function like `f(x) = if x > 0 then 1 else 0`. Now, normally, I would run the program by inputting, say, `3`, and get `f(3) = 1`, since `3` is greater than `0`. With symbolic execution, I run the program by inputting a placeholder variable, `input`, and I evaluate the program to get two cases: either `input > 0 and answer = 1` or `input <= 0 and answer = 0`. This may seem useless, but it ends up being a powerful way of analyzing programs.

---

**The connection between the two** is that symbolic execution often relies on SMT solvers during execution, to figure out if a certain path is actually possible, or if it should be discarded. For example, an SMT solver could be used to determine if `input <= 0 and answer = 0` is possible (the answer is yes, for example if `input = 0`).  In this way, SMT is kind of the "driving force" behind what makes symbolic execution feasible.